# Why the multiprocessing.Pool.map hangs with my custom partial function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I make a custom partial function as following:

(Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)])

```
In [1]: class SecPartialF(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, func, arg1):
   ...:         self.func, self.arg1 = func, arg1
   ...:     def __call__(self, arg2):
   ...:         return self.func(self.arg1, arg2)
   ...:
```

And it works for the buildin `map`:

```
In [2]: def f(x, y):
   ...:     print(x, y)
   ...:     return x + y

In [3]: list(map(SecPartialF(f, 10), range(10)))
10 0
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 4
10 5
10 6
10 7
10 8
10 9
Out[3]: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

However, it doesn't work for multiprocessing. The `pool.map` hangs and without any output:

```
In [4]: from multiprocessing import Pool

In [5]: with Pool(4) as pool:
   ...:     list(pool.map(SecPartialF(f, 10), range(10)))
   ...:
```

What's wrong with my custom partial function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your custom partial function.

The problem is that, as explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods), you need to put your top-level code in `__main__` block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        list(pool.map(SecPartialF(f, 10), range(10)))
```

Otherwise, each child process in the pool will try to create another pool of 4 more children before doing anything else.

Note that this only happens with the `spawn` and `forkserver` start methods—but Windows defaults to `spawn` (other platforms default to `fork`), so it happens to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.